# How to access each stored array variables

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I am trying to access ques array variable to store in to db.

```
        $n=0;
        while($row= mysql_fetch_row($rs)){?>
        <form name="myfm" id="myfm" method="post" action="Quiz.php">
        <table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30><td></td></td></tr> <table border=0>
        <?php $n=$n+1; ?>
        <tr><td>Question  <?php echo $n." "; echo $row[2]; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8><input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value=1><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8> <input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value=2><?php echo $row[4];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8><input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]"  value=3><?php echo $row[5];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8><input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]"  value=4><?php echo $row[6];?></td></tr>

    <?php 
        }
        echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit id='result' value='Get Result'></form>";
        ?>
        </table></table>
        </form>
```

I tried this code

```
        $n=0;
        while($row= mysql_fetch_row($rs)){
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ques']);$i++)
        {$n=$n+1;

        $questions = $_POST["ques"];
foreach ($questions as $q) {      
    print_r($_POST['ques']);
}

        mysql_query("insert into useranswer(sessid, testid, ques, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correctans,yourans) values ('".session_id()."',       $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());

        }
```

output:

```
       Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ) Array ( ['1'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['2'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) ['3'] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) )
```

But not working.please help me if you know correct correct code....If you want more code please visit this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217287/how-to-convert-this-php-page-into-a-page-that-shows-all-questions-please-read-de"

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($_Post['ques']) ??

Comment: i got this     ->                                                                                                 1array(3) { ["'1'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["'2'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["'3'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } } 2array(3) { ["'1'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["'2'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["'3'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } } 3array(3) { ["'1'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["'2'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["'3'"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } }

Answer (score 2):

In PHP variable interpolation works only within double quotes.
Iterate through the `ques` array values:

```
if (isset($_POST["ques"])) {
    $questions = $_POST["ques"];
    $ans = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($questions as $q) {      
        $ans[] = $q[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    ...
    // to insert values into respective table fields use:
   $values = implode(",", $ans);
   // then place $values into the needed position in query:
   // "... values ('... , ...., ". $values . ", ....)"
}
```

Comment: print_r($q[0][$i]); this works but how to store.do i need array $ans[][]?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this .

```
 $questions = $_POST["ques"];
    foreach ($questions as $key=>$value) {      
        echo $value;
    }
```

Comment: :( i got this -> 1ArrayArrayArray2ArrayArrayArray3ArrayArrayArray

Comment: the array you post on comment is not readable . Can you please Update your question with that output of var_dump($_POST['ques'])

Comment: do in need array to store values??

Comment: if you will not post your output how can i help you ??

Comment: ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Comment: just do print_r($_POST['ques']) in your code and update your question with that output, then i can do something for you .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103254/discussion-between-siby-xavier-and-drudge).

Comment: you must be doing something wrong with the code. Your array is so messy. CHeck your code well first.

Comment: i declared $ans=array(); now its working.Thankyou Drudge for your great support....

Comment: @SibyXavier So can you please accept/upvote the answer so that it will be helpfull for others too .